# How to fix: cross references cannot be resolved on xtext

Tags: xtext

I have the following xtext grammar defined with cross references

```
// dsl.xtext file
Students:
    'student' studentID=ID fName=STRING lName=STRING (city=STRING)? (state=STRING)?
;
Payments:
    'payment' paymentID=ID studentID=[Students] amount=INT
;

//The syntax is:
student s1001 "first name" "last name"
student s1002 "first name" "last name"

payment p101 s1002  12
```

I am  getting the following error message:

> 's1002' cannot be resolved.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hey, so you know, what you see in that question editor is not what you get. I'd recommend clicking "edit" (it's just under your question, next to "share" and "close" and looking at the syntax help on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `studentID` to `name`, cross-referencing must be done via `name`.

```
'student' name=ID fName=STRING lName=STRING (city=STRING)? (state=STRING)?
```